# htaccess - insert script name into all URL requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an application which requires an htaccess file that contains the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(tileserver\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tileserver.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I am getting 404 errors matching the following patterns:

`http://107.170.120.88/tileserver/extra5/11/331/794.png`

and:

`http://107.170.120.88/tileserver/extra5/11/331/796.grid.json`

It seems that any URL with the path:

`tileserver/extra5/`

needs to be instead:

`tileserver/tileserver.php/extra5/`

but I haven't had much luck writing an htaccess file to fix this.

If I take out the

`RewriteCond $1 !^(tileserver\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tileserver.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

the base script doesn't work, but then if I add something like:

`RewriteRule ^tileserver/extra5/(.*)$ tileserver/tileserver.php/extra5/$1`

it has no effect. How do I write this rule?

--- UPDATE ---

Here's the full htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex tileserver.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /tileserver/

<FilesMatch "\.mbtiles$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteRule ^(.+).jpeg$ $1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]

RewriteRule ^tileserver.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tileserver.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that it is sitting in a subdirectory, in which the parent (root) has this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which removes index.php from all URLs (for codeigniter). Maybe that's conflicting?

Comment: your pattern should match this url: http://107.170.120.88/tileserver/tileserver.php?/extra5/11/331/794.png

Comment: Yes - that's what I went Raphael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the datastructure like this:

`example.com/tileserver/tileserver.php`

and the url for the matching pattern 
`107.170.120.88/tileserver/extra5/11/331/794.png`

which should result in `107.170.120.88/tileserver/tileserver.php?/extra5/11/331/794.png`

your .htaccess should look something like this:

```
#turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

#use the as base for your rewrite conditions the following folder
RewriteBase /tileserver

#since we don't want to rewrite the requests pointing directly to this script, leave it
RewriteRule ^tileserver.php - [L]

#if its not a file or a folder rewrite everything to tileserver.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#everything that comes after /tileserver is passed as argument to the php script
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tileserver.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Man - still no luck - maybe there's something else in the htaccess that is keeping this from working? - I've pasted the full htaccess into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem might be the `[L]` flag.

Instead, try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(tileserver\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tileserver.php?/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^tileserver/extra5/(.*) tileserver/tileserver.php/extra5/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Didn't seem to fix it.